# Facebook Like/Share buttons not showing in dropdown menu in IE

Tags: jquery, css, facebook, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have Facebook Like/Share buttons in a dropdown menu on my website. No problem in FF & Chrome, but of course the usual problem child (IE) is acting up. For some reason, IE in it's infinite wisdom decides not to show the buttons when the container (the dropdown menu) is initially hidden.

Here's the home page of my website, which demonstrates the problem:

http://www.pricewombat.com/

If I include CSS on a page that makes the dropdown menu initially visible, then the buttons are visible.

How can this problem be fixed with a bootstrap-friendly solution??

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the same problem by using iframe version of Like/Share button.